# Cannot edit customers after Magento 1.9 Upgrade

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I am having a weird behaviour after upgrading a Magento store from 1.7 to 1.9.2

When clicking on "Manage Customers" I am shown the "Products Bought by Same Customer Manager" table. If I click on one of the entries it shows the following fatal error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit.php on line 72**

(I understand why, Magento is trying to edit a customer, with the ID and key values of the wring table)

This does not happen on my backup version of the 1.7 Version of the shop.

I believe it has something to do with this issue:
http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/fatal-error-in-manage-customers-gt-edit-magento-1410--32298.html

but I can't seem to make any progress here ... also my sql skills are rather lame :(

Any help form you guys or a hint on where to look would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found your question while searching for the same question myself after we upgraded to 1.9.2.2. The answer for me was to disable a module called Sold Together which came with a template package from Templates Master. I'm still looking into why it did that but the easiest thing was just to remove it from /app/code/local/TM/SoldTogether and refresh cache as we had to get it back working and then I'll come back and check into it more.

Cheers,
Jason

Answer (score 1):

As on the Argento theme update/upgrade instructions:

Delete following files:
app/code/local/TM/SoldTogether/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomerController.php
app/code/local/TM/SoldTogether/controllers/Adminhtml/OrderController.php

http://argentotheme.com/argento-170-171-upgrade-instructions